# What is the best way to debug an alert statement in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I'm experimenting with some Prometheus alerts with the syntax:

```
ALERT <alert name>
  IF <expression>
  [ FOR <duration> ]
  [ LABELS <label set> ]
  [ ANNOTATIONS <label set> ]
```

Is there a correct way to debug the statement on the console without having to modify the Prometheus configuration and restart it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I)
You don't need to restart Prometheus after changing or deploying alerting rules.

trigger a reload of Prometheus configuration via:

> curl -s -XPOST localhost:9090/-/reload

another option is to send `SIGHUP` to the prometheus process:

> killall -HUP prometheus

II) For evaluating the `<expression>` take a look at [recording rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/rules/). Alerting rules are configured in the same way as recording rules. You can execute them as a normal query on the Prometheus UI.